# How do I repair a damaged object?

Tags: fallout-4

As the title says. I'm not seeing a repair action for damaged items.

Do I need to scrap it and rebuild it? Sounds wrong considering the game is telling me to "repair" it.

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can only repair items that are damaged. You will get a "Repair" option appear in the bottom bar for a damaged item and a component list detailing the components required to complete the repair.

Comment: Ok thanks - I went around all my turrets and found the one that was damaged.